Flutter TabBarView take size automatically
I want to use Tab inside a Column. The best solution i got is this.  I can not use size automatically. Without using SizedBox/Container widget with the height.
My goal is to add a tab inside a colum, and add more widgets on this column.
I have tried using Expanded widget but get error.
This is the main widget were I want to fit my TabView.
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        elevation: 1,
        leading: const Icon(Icons.menu, color: Colors.white),
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text(
          "Smart Restaurant",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Card(
              elevation: 2,
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                decoration:
                    BoxDecoration(color: Colors.deepOrange.withOpacity(0.5)),
                child: const Row(
                  children: [
                    Icon(Icons.person_outline, size: 40),
                    SizedBox(width: 10),
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text("Sale", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                        Text("30-March-2024", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                color: Colors.grey.shade300,
              ),
              child: const Row(
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.search),
                  Expanded(
                      child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      hintText: 'Search Orders',
                    ),
                  ))
                ],
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 12),
            _tabSection(context),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: () {
          Get.to(() => const OrderScreen());
        },
        label: const Text('+ Create a new order'),
      ),
    );
  }

This is the Tab Widget.
Widget _tabSection(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          const TabBar(tabs: [
            Tab(
              child: Text(
                'In Progress',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.orange,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Tab(
              child: Text(
                'Completed',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.orange,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ]),
          SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: TabBarView(children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  buildContainer(),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  buildContainer(),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  buildContainer()
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  buildCompletedContainer(),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  buildCompletedContainer(),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  buildCompletedContainer()
                ],
              ),
            ]),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

This is my main screen
Here the text data is to show the distance between the TabView

please provide ui snapshot to clear clarification how to show tab bar in a column.

2 images added. If you still have question please ask.

what is your error in this code please send it.

The affected RenderFlex is:
RenderFlex#5b9d7 relayoutBoundary=up20 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE(creator: Column ← _TabControllerScope ← DefaultTabController ← TabSection ← Column ← Padding ← _SingleChildViewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#0139d] ← Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey#e35e3] ← ⋯, parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null (can use size), constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=476.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity),
